# How do I connect a bluetooth device by clicking in an item of a listview?

Tags: android, listview, bluetooth

So I created a listview that lists some devices. The problem is that I want to click one of those devices in the listview and connect to it but I do not know how to do this. I've done some code to try to connect to those devices but it won't work. Hope someone can help me woth this.

My code so far (simplified):

```
ListView lv;
ArrayList<String> devs = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> devsadap;
Button mBotOn, mBotOff, mBotDescubrir, mBotEmparejar, mBotEmp;
BluetoothAdapter mBlueAdapter;
private BluetoothSocket mBtSocket;
private BluetoothDevice mBtDevice;
private static final UUID SPP_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();
            connectToDevice(macAddress);
        }
    });
}


    //probando funciones
    private boolean connectToDevice (String macAddress){
        try {
            if (mBlueAdapter == null) {
                mBlueAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            }
            mBtDevice = mBlueAdapter.getRemoteDevice(macAddress);
            mBtSocket = mBtDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SPP_UUID);
            mBtSocket.connect();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
    //Metodo que descubre los dispositivos anteriormente emparejados(del case)
    private void pairdevs() {
        mBotDescubrir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Set<BluetoothDevice> bta = mBlueAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                String[] strings = new String[bta.size()];
                int index = 0;

                if (bta.size() > 0) {
                    for (BluetoothDevice device : bta) {
                        strings[index] = device.getName();
                        index++;
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);
                    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you enabled the Bluetooth permissions in your Manifest file?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />`

Comment: yes I have, but it won't still work